# Turn off phone debugging in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, ide, device

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 IDE.

I plugged up a Samsung phone to test with. Without even running the application I am testing, the LogCat constantly just scrolls data and it makes it difficult to focus on my app.

Is there a way to stop the console from showing phone debug logs and just show me my app when I am running it?

[image]

Comment: in drop down named as No Debuggable application select your application from it

Comment: My application isnt running yet. The phone is simply plugged up and AS is outputting all the phones logs. I just want to turn off reading the phones logs that do not deal with my application.

Comment: for a simple solution until your app is not running, add some random words to search bar then it will search for that string only

Comment: You can filter by application (once it is running), add some Regex log on the right-side text box, or simply click on "android monitor" on the bottom to minimize this window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when running the application you are able to select your application in the dropdown highlighted in green here:

[image]

This causes only the output from that specific application to be shown during debugging/running.

If you're asking to never ever show the logs from your phone, I cannot help you with that.